# What requires more energy? Destroying a planet or splitting a planet in half

Tags: physics, astronomy, science-in-society

The question is rather simple, which of the 2 option requires  more energy?

Destroying a planet comeplety or splitting a planet in directly in half

Would appreciate it if you show your calculation too

Edit: by destroy i mean by destroying it in 1 blast where there's only space dust left. Also by split i mean splitting the earth into 2 and overcoming the gravitational pull

Edit 2: again by split i mean when you split a planet in half where it won't fused back together but would be permanently be in 2 pieces

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69720/discussion-on-question-by-deako-what-requires-more-energy-destroying-a-planet-o).

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the planet is easy. But destroying one...

There is a great write up here on all your earth destruction needs

https://qntm.org/destroy

Here is the basic idea. It is very hard to "destroy" a planet. The idea of destroying it is making small enough pieces separate gravitationally from each other. In the example of splitting it in half, a planet would not stat like that for long. Gravity would pull the parts back together, and soon enough in geological terms  you will again have a sphere.  This is how the planet came together in the first place.

To sum up the link, to truly destroy the planet you would need a huge amount of antimatter, 100% of the planet's mass if you want nothing left. CLose to that if you don't want the debris sooner or later reforming into a planet